# Synchronizing two projects in one SVN

Tags: svn, version-control

Consider this SVN code repository:

```
/root
  /OldProject
    /src
  /NewProject
    /tags
    /branches
    /trunk
      /src
```

Now, let's just assume that the 'OldProject' is one of the freaknastiest abominations against software development to ever be created by human kind. 'NewProject' is supposed to be the goal implementation. Since a hard cut over is not possible; we will need to transition from one to the other slowly.

What I would like to do is allow developers to continue to commit to OldProject and have the system sync the source to the NewProject for specific directories, thus keeping both trees up to date. My goal is to make it so that other developers do not need to change their system configuration. It needs to be seamless (so SVN externals is most likely not a good option). The only thing I can think of is to use a staging area, ie a Jenkins CI workspace, for the OldProject and have it rsync & commit to a workspace for the NewProject.

This seems to work but it just feels 'wrong'. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to port all changes from `OldProject` into `NewProject` automatically so the latter is an exact copy of the former? How are you supposed to develop NewProject?

Comment: Just specific directories. I'll make a note of that. Thanks.

Comment: What makes a hard cutover not possible?

Comment: @alroc: I suspect poor genetics and a lack of access to contraceptives. eg: poor developers.

Comment: Enabling poor developers just keeps them at the same level of skill. Improve, or get out.

Comment: @alroc: agreed, however, I don't have duty assignment authority for the project in question. :-/ Therefor we must adapt and overcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It needs to be seamless (so SVN externals is most likely not a good option)

Please elaborate: for me externals from some nodes of NewProject to some nodes of OldProject **is most seamless** (and easy) solution

> Jenkins CI workspace, for the OldProject and have it rsync & commit to a workspace for the NewProject

Is DRY Principle violation (with single difference - Jenkins instead human) with additional not needed layer: it can be (with some work) implemented by post-commit hook in repo

Comment: Sorry for the lag. I went back and read up on externals. My previous understanding of how it worked was wrong and it appears that this will be an acceptable solution. I disagree that the proposed option violates DRY but that is mostly a situation of our setup, of which I did not provide specifics. Thanks for the comment.